# how to block a link on a flash object with javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

It is possible to block a link from flash object? (Link is hardcoded inside a flash object).

Comment: no, it is not possible to do that. Why would you want to do it?

Answer (score 2):

no, the link is managed by flash plugin.

At most you can just overlap the flash object with an element (with a transparent background) so the link is not clickable (but this is not a real solution since it can be circumvented)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, since Flash "lives in it's own world" in the browser. All JavaScript sees is an object, it doesn't know what's in there.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, generate a new swf which embeds the current flash swf & disable its mouse events, using:

```
mc.mouseEnabled = false;
```

You can control the new swf by defining an **ExternalInterface** & calling from javascript, using:

```
document.getElementById('flash-obj').ExternalMethodInFlash();
```